# Mapping Cloud Correcting Function using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, cloudmasking

I'm using the JavaScript API of Google Earth Engine. I'm running code given [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b241893c90a7de5ee17e384dc1d282d7) and described in the developers forum [here](https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers/c/i63DS-Dg8Sg/m/AdkarNBeBQAJ). The functions supplied work independently of each other, but at the bottom, there is a function called `wrapIt` for applying the entire process across ImageCollections. However, I've found that this function only masks clouds, but not shadows. Its output is the same as the `Cloud Masked Mosaic` layer, while I would like it to have the same output as the `After CloudScore and Shadow Masking` layer.

[image: Before Masking layer]

`Before Masking` layer

[image: Cloud Masked Mosaic layer]

`Cloud Masked Mosaic` layer

[image: After CloudScore and Shadow Masking layer]

`After CloudScore and Shadow Masking` layer

I've tried editing this code to make `wraptIt` mask out the shadows, given [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/bc2597adaeff17a519b0e9702cdcf52b). I'm very inexperienced with JavaScript, and am unsure why it doesn't work. Further notes on my code: in shadowed areas that the `After CloudScore and Shadow Masking` layer masks out, the cloudShadowMask value is 1 in the `After CloudScore and Shadow Masking` layer and 0 in the `s2swrapped` layer. As well, the `s2swrapped` layer has two cloudScore bands.